# How do I create a bar chart with percentage values in Python (Plotly Express)?

Tags: python, data-visualization, percentage, plotly-express

I have a data frame that displays everything I need, but initially my 'No Show (%)' rate calculation displayed in decimal places:

```
                          Groups and Classes  Booked  Arrived  No Show (n)  No Show (%)
6            Supervised Exercise Program     121       57           64        5e-01
0                      Active Living 101       4        2            2        5e-01
2      Eating Well the Mediterranean Way      38       24           14        4e-01
5                                   MBCT     101       66           35        3e-01
4                  Healthy Meal Planning      33       22           11        3e-01
3                                  Grief      56       46           10        2e-01
1                         Craving Change     115       95           20        2e-01
Total                                NaN     468      312          156        3e-01
```

This then gives me the following chart:

```
mergedgcfig = mergedgc.sort_values('No Show (%)', ascending=True)
fig2 = px.bar(mergedgcfig, x='No Show (%)', y='Groups and Classes', text='No Show (%)', title='<b>Groups and classes no show rate</b>', template='simple_white', width=600, height=400)
fig2.update_traces(marker_color='#3EB595')
fig2.update_layout(uniformtext_minsize=8, uniformtext_mode='hide', autosize=False, title_x=0.7, title_font_family ="Calibri")
fig2.write_image('fig2.png')
```

[image]

Which is fine and all but I'd like to display my data labels in percentages instead.

```
mergedgc['No Show (%)'] = mergedgc['No Show (%)'].transform(lambda x: '{:,.0%}'.format(x))

                      Groups and Classes  Booked  Arrived  No Show (n) No Show (%)
6            Supervised Exercise Program     121       57           64         53%
0                      Active Living 101       4        2            2         50%
2      Eating Well the Mediterranean Way      38       24           14         37%
5                                   MBCT     101       66           35         35%
4                  Healthy Meal Planning      33       22           11         33%
3                                  Grief      56       46           10         18%
1                         Craving Change     115       95           20         17%
Total                                NaN     468      312          156         33%
```

So the data frame ends up displaying what I want but the problem is when I try to put this into a bar chart, it reads the percentages as a categorical variable.
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I basically just want my No Show calculation to be expressed as percentages and display those percentages in the bar chart data labels. It looks like as soon as you add a % symbol, it converts to a string. I thought recognizing percentages would have been built in so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me so I can get the first figure to display, but with percentage data labels?

Comment: Any reason you couldn't just multiply your fractions by 100?  Since you've already specified that they're percentages in your x-axis label?

Comment: The problem is that you are converting to a string explicitly when you perform `.transform(lambda x: '{:,.0%}'.format(x))`.

Comment: @mdrishan the problem is when I multiply by 100 that just gives me a whole number, I want to express a percentage with the percentage symbol.

Comment: So you want to include the percentage symbol on the bars themselves?

Comment: @mdrishan yes just like how you would normally do it in excel based on your data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the `text` field to `text=[f'{i}%' for i in mergedgcfig['No Show (%)']]`.

```
mergedgcfig = mergedgc.sort_values('No Show (%)', ascending=True)
fig2 = px.bar(mergedgcfig, x='No Show (%)', y='Groups and Classes',  title='<b>Groups and classes no show rate</b>',
              template='simple_white', width=600, height=400, text=[f'{i}%' for i in mergedgcfig['No Show (%)']])
fig2.update_traces(marker_color='#3EB595')
fig2.update_layout(uniformtext_minsize=8, uniformtext_mode='hide', autosize=False, title_x=0.7, title_font_family ="Calibri")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this works! But it ends up adding a % symbol to the decimal (e.g. 0.53%), and even when I multiply it by 100 it keeps giving me a decimal place on the data labels (e.g. 53.0%).

Comment: After multiplying by 100, round to 0 decimal places.  `round(mergedgcfig['No Show (%)'] * 100, 0)`

Comment: Instead of rounding, you can convert to an int.  `mergedgcfig['No Show (%)'] = (mergedgcfig['No Show (%)']*100).astype(int)`.